# Image-trace in Illustrator - How to join objects together?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, image-trace

I have traced a logo from a jpeg in illustrator. It is two colours - black and blue.
When it was made it ended up with an extra blue shape outlining the some of the black. Is there a way to add the blue shape to the black rather than just recolouring it all to the black? 
I'm relatively new to Illustrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the pathfinder tool is the answer for you. Go to `Window > Pathfinder` to open the Pathfinder window, select both shapes you want to join and press the `Unite` button in the pathfinder window (it's the first one.)

That should do the trick.